# An article before house

Tags: articles

Why in the sentence **The dream of  the Algerians is a fountain in the house.** "the" is used before house? Is house used here as the concept of house?

---

Everyone has his own idea of house and "the" is referring to this concept and the dream of Algerians is described using a listener's concept of house.Is this correct explanation?

Comment: Algerians dream of having a fountain in their courtyards. The fountains are not in the houses....

Comment: What article should I use if I would say the sentence "Algerians dream of having a fountain in their courtyards." without "their"?

Comment: Nothing: Algerians dream of having fountains in courtyards. COMPARE: Algerians love fountains in courtyards [sounds better, and is grammatical]., It's not like French. General statements can use a plural word. But why leave out "their" unless you want a general idea in which case switch to love instead.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed countryard is in the plural form in your response. Edited: "Algerians dream of having a fountain in (?)courtyard." I'm curios about usage an article in this sentence if "their" is omitted

Comment: "A fountain in courtyard" is not grammatical: fountains in courtyards or a fountain in a courtyard.  I have already explained that above.

Comment: So, I should use the indefinite article, yes?

Comment: Here's a tip: I should use the indefinite article, shouldn't I? Learn tags, they will help you speak better English. (J'avais deux copines algériennes à la fac à Paris, il y a 30 ans!! Malheureusement, perdues de vu.)

Comment: Regardless of the exact location of Algerian fountains, _in the house_ is a set phrase with various meanings, one of them being  'in one's own home'.